# xCode publish App Icon Error

Tags: xcode

When I try to publish my app to the app store, it shows me two errors:

First: Missing required icon, the bundle does not contain an app icon for iphone/ipod of exactly 57x57 in png format for iOS version <7

Second: Your binary is not optimized for iphone5 - new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4 inch display on iPhone 5

Does my icon need to be 57x57 or can I use any size and the system will resize it for me?

thanks.

Comment: Yes.  You must have a 57x57 icon... otherwise it wouldn't have shown you the error.  Also, you have to support the iPhone 5 display.  And probably the iPhone 6 for good measure.

Comment: DevBox is a good tool to automatically resize icons, otherwise you have to use Photoshop or GIMP or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need a 57x57 png in your build. I would recommend reading the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines: App Icons](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppIcons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH19-SW1) material.

Answer (score 1):

When u publishing an app icon you shouldn't use transparency it is forbidden apple does it for u automatically.

When you changed png to jpg the background became white , and solved your problem retroactively:-)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution for that.

Whenever you added icon to the image asset, but it's not showing after you archive the app, its because xcode requires jpg image, if you only change the extension .png to .jpg, it won't work.

Took me awhile to found out.

Comment: Well I use png and it is fine

Comment: Oh...I guess that's not the solution then, but anyways it was the problem for me

Comment: When u publishing an app icon you shouldn't use transparency it is forbidden apple does it for u automatically . I think this was ur problem

Comment: Oh, but I changed the extension to jpg which means it would automatically become white background, am I correct? 0.0

Comment: I made an answer consider to accept it for feature users so they will know what to do . - cheers

Comment: I think we have some misunderstanding between us. So when I change the extension transparent(png) to jpg, it doesn't work. But when I use photoshop and save as jpg it works.

Comment: when you renaming the file to jpg it is still png . when u saving as jpg it removes the png's tranparency and it becomes a real jpg.

Comment: It is still better to use png in apple device since apple somehow optimizes its size.

Comment: @user3351949 Thank you for your patient explaining this to me.